# change path of drupal links & menu etc

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drupal, themes

Is there an option in Drupal to make all the URL’s that Drupal generates point to somewhere else?

For example, from path: "/" or "mydomain.com" to "http://apps.facebook.com/myapp”, I know there is already Facebook plugin but it has a lot of bugs.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you should be able to modify the $base_path variable in your site's settings.php file.

For example, by default when Drupal creates a path to a page like 'About Us', This would then by link people to something like:

```
    /about-us
```

(which is equivalent to http://www.mydrupalsite.com/about-us)

If you change the $base_path variable in your settings.php file to, for example:

```
    $base_path = "http://www.myotherdrupalsite.com";
```

Then Drupal will render your links like, e.g. http://www.myotherdrupalsite.com/about-us

Comment: the problem is that its apps.facebook.com/myapp/... is that metter?

Comment: You can set `$base_path = "http://apps.facebook.com/myapp";` which will make all of your links have that base path at the beginning of the URL. However, once that setting is made, all of your links will link externally to Facebook and your users will not remain on your Drupal site.